# Does multipart/x-mixed-replace wait for client requests?

Tags: http, multipart-mixed-replace

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to slow down the server when it's sending multipart/xmixed-replace responses.  I want my client to try to rate limit a motion jpeg stream.  I've found a lot of documentation about what the **server** sends in an HTTP response but nothing about what the **client** sends.

What does the client send, if anything, after each part in a multipart/x-mixed-replace response?  If it doesn't send anything, does the server just keep piling on the parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I think the multipart thing is a red herring because the concept of multipart is just to delineate content types within the same message body. So from a server perspective (in terms of the rate at which content is sent) it is not really different from sending a single big chunk of data.

So, I am wondering if you can the Range header to only request a specific range - one "part" at a time.

Start counting bytes from the end of the response headers. When you reach the end of the first part, note the number of bytes read and close the connection. Send a request for
the same document but specify the starting Range as the bytes at the end of chunk. Again, read the response, when you reach the end of the part, add the current response bytes to the previous, close the connection and repeat ad nauseam...

Haven't tried it, but sounds like it would work provided the server supported range headers and provided you were able to do some patching on the client side.

Might be easier to write a client-side proxy that rate limits by dropping packets ...

Answer (score 0):

Try using LiveHTTPHeaders plugin for Mozilla.  I went to Gmail (which uses AJAX) and followed the conversation between the client and server for a few minutes.  It seems this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

At the HTTP level I dont think the client sends anything. The server assumes that as long as the connection is open it can keep sending the response.

I dont think there is an easy HTTP-level solution to the problem because there is no "ack" concept in the client-server exchange.

There are obviously TCP-/IP level solutions to this problem.

I am wondering if the client can do something differently when it actually receives the server's response headers and recognizes that the response is multipart - whether it can then abort the connect and open a new non-keep alive one and just get the parts one by one...